# Remove certain strings from filenames inside a folder

Tags: python, filenames

I have a folder that contains a bunch of text files.

```
32167.pdf.txt
20988.pdf.txt
45678.pdf.txt
:
:
99999.pdf.txt
```

I would like to remove ".pdf" from all the filenames inside that folder (As showed below).

```
32167.txt
20988.txt
45678.txt
:
:
99999.txt
```

I tried to use os to do it but throwing me an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.txt' -> '.txt'`

Here is my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/CodingStark/folder/'):
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace('.pdf', ''))
```

I am wondering are there any other ways to achieve this instead of using os? Or os is the fastest way to do it? Thank you!!

Comment: @Steve But this code gave me an error: ````FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.txt' -> '.txt'````

Comment: It would be helpful to know what code line that error refers to.

Comment: Oh...it's NOT working.  Sorry.  I misread the question

Comment: @RoccoFortuna it refers to this line ````os.rename(filename, filename.replace('.pdf', ''))````

Comment: @Steve That's ok!!

Comment: I would suggest printing out `filename` before you call `os.rename()` to be sure about what you're passing to it.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe you have some txt file like *.txt that causes the issue?

Comment: @CodingStark, I don't see a green checkmark.  Did that solve your problem?  I'd like to know that you're all set.

Comment: @Steve It did solve my problem. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what's wrong.  `filename` will contain just the file's name, not a complete path.  Try this:

```
dir = '/Users/CodingStark/folder/'
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    os.rename(dir + filename, dir + filename.replace('.pdf', ''))
```

Comment: If already using `os.path`, it is better to use `os.path.join` than to use string concatenation (`+`)

Comment: Technically, sure.  But if you know your code is never going to end up on a Windows machine, it doesn't really make any difference.  And won't Windows now even take paths with a mixture of forward and backfacing slashes? - If this were code that were going into a long lived server project, I'd probably make that change per your suggestion.  But if I just wanted to rename a bunch of files in a directory one time, then the code is already useless anyway, so why bother.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) when working with paths. It has alternatives for most of the `os` functions and it just makes more sense to use and is definitely more portable.

To the task in hand:

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path('/Users/CodingStark/folder/')
for path in root.glob("*.pdf.txt"):
    path.rename(path.with_name(path.name.replace(".pdf", "")))
#               or:
#               path.with_suffix('').with_suffix(".txt")
#               or:
#               str(path).replace(".pdf", "")
```

Comment: I tried to run the code but the filenames still didn't make any changes after executed the code.

Comment: Hi @CodingStark you are right. Sorry about that. I missed the fact that `with_suffix` only changes the last suffix in case of more than one. Fixed it above with alternatives